# I want to create containerd/config.toml file for local lxc containers

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, lxc, containerd

I've been trying and looking for a solution to use my local lxc containers images to get loaded in my local k8s cluster.

By this, I have a Dev Environment, which has few lxc containers and images. I have created a cluster with the help of kubeadm, containerd and calico.

Everything is running well so far. I haven't look into networking yet.
The problem arises here is that from my deployment the k8 is trying to get the image from docker instead of local storage. Help me out.

I have try this

```
`/etc/containerd/config.toml
[plugins."io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.lxc"]
    root_path = "/snap/bin/lxc"`
```

The error I got when I described the pod

```
`Pod/lxc-deployment-55df87595f-rdth8   Failed to pull image "nginx-image": failed to pull and     unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx-image:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx-image:latest": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed`
```

Also when I change  `snapshotter = "overlayfs" to lxc`
My node gets into `NOT READY` status

Comment: please visit https://askubuntu.com or https://superuser.com